# ¿Como obtener el ultimo numero impar de cierta cantidad de números ingresados en un arreglo?

Tags: java, algoritmos

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int a[];
  int ta;
  int aux = 0;

  String vi = "";
  ta = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño del vector"));

  a = new int[ta];

  for (int i = 0; i < ta; i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor del vector en la posicion " + i));
    vi = vi + "[" + a[i] + "]";

  }

  int impar = 0;
  int posicionimpar = 0;
  int ultimaposicionimpar = 0;
  int ultimoimpar = a[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < ta; i++) {

    if (ultimaposicionimpar == 0) {
      ultimoimpar = a[i];

    }
    if (a[i] % 2 != 0) {
      a[i] = impar;
      i = posicionimpar;
    }
    if (posicionimpar > ultimaposicionimpar) {
      ultimaposicionimpar = posicionimpar;
    }
    if (i == ultimaposicionimpar) {

      ultimoimpar = a[i];

    }
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores en las posiciones son:" + vi +
    "\n  El ultimo numero impar es: " + ultimoimpar);
}
```

Comment: Por curiosidad no es mejor correr el arreglo inverso y el primero haces un break?

Comment: ¿Su código muestra algún error ? ¿ Resultados equivocados? podría añadir el problema que tiene

Comment: El resultado que me sale no es el ultimo numero impar ingresado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay Varias líneas de código que están de más en su código. Si desea obtener solo el "último número impar ingresado"  bastará con iterar en el `for`  este lo hace de forma ascendente es decir en  orden en el cuál fueron ingresados e ir comparando si es impar si lo es se añade a la variable `ultimoimpar` , no veo necesidad de comparar ni guardar indices o posiciones.

Su Código podría quedar *(si hay dudas  o se me escapó algo, no dude en comentar)*

```
int ultimoimpar= -1;
//int pos = -1;
for (int i=0; i<ta; i++){
    if (a[i]%2!=0){//verificamos si Es Impar
        // si lo es asignamos a la variable
        ultimoimpar = a[i]; // Obtengo el elemento impar evaluado
        //Aquí setea la posicion si desea
        //pos = i;
    }
}
//Si es diferente al valor inicial es porque
// no hay impares
if(ultimoimpar!= -1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores en las posiciones son:"+vi +
    "\n  El ultimo numero impar es: "+ultimoimpar);
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Hay Números Impares");
}
```

Ejm del Funcionamiento , supongamos que tenemos el array ingresado con los valores `5,10,7,8,3,20`

```
Iteraciones  ||  valor evaluado || valor de la variable 
                del array             ultimoimpar

     1       ||      5          || 5   // Encuentra el 5 lo asigna a la variable
     2       ||      10         || 5   // Sigue siendo 5 ya que el 10 es par
     3       ||      7          || 7   //  Encuentra el 7 lo asigna a la variable
     4       ||      8          || 7   // Sigue siendo 7 ya que el 8 es par
     5       ||      3          || 3   //  Encuentra el 3 lo asigna a la variable
     6       ||      20         || 3   //Lo Ignora ya que 20 es par (valor final)
```

Al Final la variable tendrá el valor de 3 que es el último número impar ingresado

Comment: Pero si tengo varios impares, todos ellos se almacenaran en la variable ultimoimpar ¿Como entonces obtengo solo el ultimo impar que ingrese

Comment: Disculpen mi ignorancia:(

Comment: @GlendaGuerreroFlores añadí una explicación con valores e  iteraciones , espero sea de ayuda para mejor comprensión. Si tiene dudas igual puede comentar. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias ya entendi